# PHP функция imagecopy по центру

Tags: php

По умолчанию для функции imagecopy расположение логотипа, лево-верх.

```
imagecopy (resource dst_im, resource src_im, int dst_x, int dst_y, int src_x, int src_y, int src_w, int src_h)
```

Как можно сделать чтобы для изображений любых размеров, накладывалось всегда по центру?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

не лево-верх, а вы сами задаете координаты.

к примеру у нас есть картинка 10х20, и нам нужно разместить её на картинке 20х40

```
imagecopy ($img_20x20, $img_10x10, round((20-10)/2), round((40-20)/2), 0, 0, 10, 20);
```

Comment: Мы не знаем размеры картинок изначально.

Comment: ну так [узнайте][1].


  [1]: http://ua.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php